# If condition issues in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I know its a basic question but I'm facing an issue related to it that i'm getting data from backend service.

From service I got [] in response. and I'm comparing it with my model class array. Mean if my model class array is qual to [], than I have to perform something.

My code is this,

```
    let addonCategory = subCategoryModel![tappedIndex.section].items[tappedIndex.row].addonCategory
    print(addonCategory as Any)

    if addonCategory == "[]"{
      print("Hello")
    }
    else {
         print("Hi")
    }
```

But when i compare it with [] brackets it shows error message that,

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[AddonCategoryModel]?'

How can i compare it with brackets?

Comment: actually you are comparing string ("[]") with an array of model ('[AddonCategoryModel]?') and that is not allowed.

Comment: u try to compare a String with an Array ... So waht u basicly want is, that when addonCategory is empty, u print "Hello". ... or not? Ah, and when u print addonCategory as Any, u get "[]" ... i understand.

Comment: Why you are comparing array type with string ?

Comment: Not related But Don't forcefully unwrap the options values use guard or lf statement

Comment: its coming [ ] brackets from backend thats why. @MiteshDobareeya

Comment: It's an empty array that's it.

Comment: You can not compare `"[]"`(string) with `addonCategory`(array). Check with `addonCategory.isEmpty()` rather than any string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether an array has an element or not.

```
if addonCategory.count > 0 {
    // array has element
} else {
   // array hasn't element
}
```

Alternatively you can use `guard let` or `if let` to check.

**Using if let**

```
if let addonCategory = subCategoryModel[tappedIndex.section].items[tappedIndex.row].addonCategory, addonCategory.isEmpty {
    print(addonCategory)

    print("Hello")
} else {
    print("Hi")
}
```

Comment: thats right. a better way is to call `if addonCategory.isEmpty {} else {}`

Comment: Yeah, thats also true !!

Comment: when iam not right, the compiler already tells u to use isEmpty ... :) or is it my linting tool? :)

Comment: No, compiler won't complain if you use `count` property of an array.

Comment: it isn't going inside the if condition. @Mahendra GP

Comment: if the addonCategory is Empty, it will go into the else block

Comment: it should go inside if condition if it is [ ] brackets from backend. @BjörnRo

Comment: the backend doesnt send u "[ ]", the backend did send u a list of empty categories. U only made your print look like "[ ]" because u printed the variable as Any

Comment: I think @raheem is misinterpreting `[]`.

Comment: may is suggest u to put a breakpoint on the line before the if, and in the console of xcode u do `po subCategoryModel[tappedIndex.section].items[tappedIndex.row].addonCategory` ... if it shows u Optiona(xyz) than put a "!" on the end of the po call

Comment: if u print an object, what is basicly printed is the hidden variable "description" on the object. That means, this description represents the objects value in a string. So to speak, u dont see the real object, u see the description of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array properties on `addonCategory`. It is not of type `String`

```
let addonCategory = subCategoryModel![tappedIndex.section].items[tappedIndex.row].addonCategory

print(addonCategory.count == 0 ? "Hello" : "Hi")
```

Here I have used `ternary` operator instead of traditional `if-else` syntax.